# A new function added to script.js causes the other two scripts to not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Thanks to everyone's help this project is actually coming along and I'm learning some really cool skills thanks to everyone for their help.  Especially the guys at Techstream and FormGet.  Using some code at Techstream I was able to modify to suit the data elements my folks are working with so they can add folder names and then assign descriptors to each folder name or they can delete lines from the list before they submit and have them inserted into the database.  So the next step was to design a function so when they press submit, a php script would fire and insert the array into the database.  However when I placed `insertFunction()` into `script.js` it causes the other two functions that allow the user to add or delete lines in the form to not work.  Can someone take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I thought it was possible to have multiple functions within the same script.js file.  Here's my code.  Obvious function addRow and function deleteRow are what allow the user to add or delete rows from the user input form.  And they work like a charm until I added the third function function `insertFunction()` to script.js.  When `insertFunction()` is added it seems to disable `addRow` and `deleteRow`.  Can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for any suggestions!

```
function addRow(tableID) {/*this function allows the user to add more rows to the form to a maximum of 10000*/
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 10000){                           // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Contact Records Management if you have more than 10000 records.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) { /*this function allows the user to delete rows from the form but requires they have at least 1 row*/
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("You must have at least 1 folder.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

function insertFunction() { /*This is the function that takes the user input from the form, validates and sends to filedetailinsert.php for insert into db*/

var officecode = document.getElementById("officecode").value;
var myusername = document.getElementById("myusername").value;
var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
var creator = document.getElementById("creator").value;
var officechief = document.getElementById("officechief").value;
var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
var BX_NAME = document.getElementById("BX_NAME").value;
var BX_fileseries = document.getElementById("BX_fileseries").value;
var BX_classification = document.getElementById("BX_classification").value;
var BX_media = document.getElementById("BX_media").value;

/*Returns successful data submission message when the entered data is inserted into database */

var dataString = 'officecode1=' +officecode+ 'myusername1=' +myusername+ 'day1=' +day+ 'month1=' +month+ 'year1=' +year+ 'creator1=' +creator+ 'officechief1=' +officechief+ 'status1=' +status+ 'BX_NAME1=' +BX_NAME+ 'BX_fileseries1=' +BX_fileseries 'BX_classification1=' +BX_classification+ 'BX_media1=' +BX_media;

if 

(officecode == '' || myusername == '' || day == '' || month == '' || year == '' || creator == '' || officechief == '' || status == '' || BX_NAME == '' || BX_fileseries == '' || BX_classification == '' || BX_media == '') 

{
/*the statement above checks to see if all fields are populated.  If there are empty fields it displays a message "Please Complete All Fields" and will not proceed to the $.ajax action below.  When the user clicks ok on the error message they remain at the user input form to populate the field(s) they left blank.  If all fields are populated then the $.ajax action fires, invoking filedetailinsert.php script to place the data into the database.*/


alert(Please Complete All Fields");


} 

else 

{
//AJAX code to submit form comes next

$.ajax(

{
    type: "POST",
url: "filedetailinsert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) 

    {
        alert(hmtl);
    }

} 

);

}


return false;



}
```

Comment: Something: `alert(Please Complete All Fields");` is missing a starting quotation `"`

Comment: As above. It is obvious  due to the SO syntax highlighter. I **highly** recommend using a code editor that does the same. Also, use the JS console in your browser, it would have highlighted the error

Comment: But would that syntax error in one function cause the first two functions to cease working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(Please Complete All Fields");
```

A missing double quote at the begining of the message.

Should be:

```
alert("Please Complete All Fields");
```

Comment: As I asked above, would that syntax error in one function cause the first two functions to cease working?

Comment: alrighty then! I'll correct the error and see what happens! thanks so much to everyone for their help!

Comment: Yep...that solved the problem! Thanks to lolka_bolka, Steve and user887675 for your help!